# Firebase Phone Authentication in Flutter using Provider

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, bloc, flutter-provider

I just found a provider for state management and am really curious to know how can I impliment **Firebase Phone Auth** with **Provider**. Currently I am using stateful Widgets for state management and its biolerplate, but my phone auth is working.

I need help to know how can I achieve the same using Provider.

Any tutorials, references or implementation would be fine.

Current Auth Provider Class:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:ninja_firebase_test1/models/user.dart';

class AuthService{

 final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

 //create user object based on FireBaseUser
 User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user){
   return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid):null;
 }

 //auth change user stream
 Stream<User> get user {
  return _auth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFirebaseUser); 
 }


 // Verify Phone Number 
 // Signup with phone Function, return user id 
 // 




 // sign out
 Future signOut() async {
  try{
    return await _auth.signOut();
  }  catch(e){
    print(e.toString());
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Asking for tutorials is off topic on Stack Overflow. Search engines are probably a better place for that. But if you're having problems signing in with a one-time password to a phone number, edit your question to include the [minimal code that reproduces that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and someone may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthService{

 final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance; 

  //create user object based on FireBaseUser

 User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user){
  return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid):null;
 }

 // define _auth.verifyPhoneNumber() here

 Future signInWithPhoneNumber(String smsCode) async {
  try{ 
    final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
    verificationId: verificationId,
    smsCode: smsCode,
   );
   AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
   FirebaseUser user= result.user;
   return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
  } catch (e){
    print(e.toString());
    return null;
  }
}
```